# Combine two arrays in PHP with the same keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays like this.

```js
$result_1 = array(
[0] => array ("id" => "a1", "label" => "A1"),
[1] => array ("id" => "a2", "label" => "A2"));

$result_2 = array(
[0] => array ("id" => "b1", "label" => "B1"));
```

How to combine $result_1 and $result_2 into a new array $result so it will give me a result like this?

```js
 $result = array(
[0] => array ("id" => "a1", "label" => "A1"),
[1] => array ("id" => "a2", "label" => "A2"),
[2] => array ("id" => "b1", "label" => "B1"));
```

If I'm using `$result = array_merge($result_1,$result_2)`, it will return only 1 index. If I'm using `$result = array($result_1,$result_2)`, it will return only 2 indexes. I want it return all indexes. Please help me, thanks.

Comment: use `$result = $result_1 + $result_2`

Comment: have you try array_values()? this will reset your index

Comment: @jitendrapurohit didn't work. It returned only 1 index.

Comment: @RafaelShkembi i've tried array_values(), but it returned null

Comment: have you tryed the answer of @MathieuLescaudron

Comment: `array_merge($result_1,$result_2)` will give the expected result you have presented. You've wrote *it will return only 1 index.* - what does it mean? Check `array_merge` again

Answer (score 1):

use array_walk as you have array in your result_2 variable combined with array_push. it does the job, but keep in mind it alters first array http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

```
$result_1 = array(
    0 => array ("id" => "a1", "label" => "A1"),
    1 => array ("id" => "a2", "label" => "A2")
);

$result_2 = array(
    0 => array ("id" => "b1", "label" => "B1")
);

array_walk($result_2, function($item) use (&$result_1) {

    array_push($result_1, $result_2);
});
print_r($result_1);

Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [id] => a1 [label] => A1 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [id] => a2 [label] => A2 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [id] => b1 [label] => B1 ) 
)
```